# SSHD Config checking in bash script

Tags: bash, security, ssh, redhat, openssh

I'm currently making a simple security audit script, which will print OK/Error for every mismatch in configuration.
Scenario is next - for example, for SSHD_Config I've put next if case:

```
if [ "`grep -E ^Protocol /etc/ssh/sshd_config`" == "Protocol 1" ]; then
  echo "Protocol should be set to 2";
fi
```

The problem is - what if there is more than one space between some variable and its value? (Protocol 2 or PermitRootLogin  No for ex.); `/*s` , `/s` and similar tricks didn't help.

Does anybody have a sample for checking SSHD Config in a bash script to post cases here?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-E` option of grep puts it in extended regular expressions mode. So, you can use extended regular expressions (`^Protocol +1` means a line starting with `Protocol`, followed by 1 or more spaces, and then character `1`):

```
if grep -Eq '^Protocol +1' /etc/ssh/sshd_config; then
  echo "Protocol should be set to 2";
fi
```

`[yY]` means character `y` or `Y`:

```
if grep -Eq '^PermitEmptyPasswords +[yY][eE][sS]' /etc/ssh/sshd_config; then
  echo "PermitEmptyPasswords should be set to no";
elif grep -Eq '^PermitEmptyPasswords +[nN][oO]' /etc/ssh/sshd_config; then
  echo "PermitEmptyPasswords meets requirements";
fi
```

And many other interesting features. Notes:

- You should probably consider cases where you have more than one matching line in the `sshd_config` file.
- The `-q` grep option suppresses the printing of matching lines. grep just exits with status 0 if a matching line has been found, else with status 1 (not found) or 2 (error).
- The `if` statement can be directly followed by a list of commands to execute. If the exit status of the list is 0, the `then` branch is taken. In our case the list is just the `grep`.

Comment: How to put case for Yes and No (for example PermitEmptyPasswords) then?
For example:
if grep -Eq '^PermitEmptyPasswords +yes' /etc/ssh/sshd_config; then
  echo "Value does not meet requirements";
  else echo "Value does meet requirements" <<<- what to input on this place, a case or one more if case with "no" value?

Comment: @Kristian Added this to my answer. Try maybe to find a documentation on extended regular expressions, this is a very useful knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for tips, I'm new at scripting, so some of the procedures are not clear 1/1 for me for now.

Comment: Sorry for possible spam, it works for spaces between variable/value, but what if the line begins with blank space then word Protocol for example ?

Comment: `^ *Protocol +1` but really, have a look at regular expressions, I insist that it is something to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if [[ $(cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | awk '/^Protocol/{print $2}') != 2 ]]; then 
    echo "Protocol should be set to 2"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grep to get protocol 2 lines.

Then remove protocol 1 lines that may include 2 such as Protocol 2,1

At last the hash should be ruled out. In the end echo the needed string.

In grep added -i in grep for case insensitivity

```
grep -i "Protocol 2" /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -v "#"|grep -v "Protocol 1"|| echo "Protocol 2 is needed"
```